# Distributions in Combinatorics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A auditorium has $20$ chairs, all aligned in a row. How many ways can $5$ people be seated, so that no two people are sitting next to each other?

My Solution, where there is something incorrect:

We can let there be $15$ chairs, where there is space left for $5$ people.

Thus there are $16$ spaces to choose the $5$ people. Then, we arrange those $5$ people.

Hence, we get our solution is $\displaystyle{\binom{16}{5}\cdot 5!}=\boxed{524160}.$

However, I think I am missing something. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why $15$ chairs?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your reasoning isn’t explained clearly enough for me to tell whether it’s correct.

Comment: There are $5$ people. We set out $15$ empty chairs, which is we can put $5$ people between them or at the ends so none are together

Comment: ^ That is the crucial missing explanation

Comment: But you only need $9$ chairs to fit $5$ people: full, empty, full, empty, full ... and so on.

Comment: @obscurans: I still don’t see what the OP is thinking. There are $5$ filled chairs, and the remaining $15$ must be distributed to $6$ slots, one at each end of the row and four between adjacent people. Each of the interior slots must get at least one chair, so there are $11$ chairs to be distributed arbitrarily to the $6$ slots. This can be done in $\binom{11+6-1}{5-1}=\binom{16}5$ ways, so the final binomial coefficient is correct, but the OP’s reasoning still isn’t clear to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not too fluent. It is hard for me to explain. Your idea seems close to what I was thinking, but why aren't we multiplying by $5!$?

Comment: It's a stars and bars argument all over again. Place 15 of the 20 chairs outright, with 16 spaces between them and at the ends. Place the 5 other chairs (with people sitting on them) in any 5-set of these 16 spaces.

Comment: @obscurans: Ah, okay; I tend to think of the people as the bars and the chairs as the stars, but that works too.

Comment: @FrostBite: The $5!$ is fine. I didn’t mention it because it’s self-explanatory; my only question was about how you arrived at the binomial coefficient, and **obscurans** has cleared that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:- I can't comment so I am posting it as an answer.

I don't think you need to multiply by $5!$.

Comment: hmm, how? Don't we need to consider the arrangements of the $5$ people?

Comment: @Frost Bite No. I don't think so. But the question seems just a bit ambiguous (to me) as it doesn't mention whether people are distinguishable or not.

Comment: ok, thanks :) Seems reasonable!

Comment: If it was distinguishable (like you assumed), I think you would also have to multiply by 15! after multiplying by 5! to consider arrangements of the remaining 15 people.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I thought of it:

[image]

First, put a space in between the people. This needs $9$ seats, and there are $11$ unused seats.

[image]

The $11$ seats can be then placed in $6$ spots. For spots $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$, since the chairs are indistinguishable, it does not matter whether we put a new chair to the right or to the left of the existing chair.

This is simple stars and bars, which gives ${11+6-1} \choose {6-1}$ ways of putting people in the chairs.

Finally, we need to multiply by $5!$ to swap the order of the $5$ people.